# Google Maps V3 Custom Overlay children stopped receiving mouse events

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Custom Overlay (google.maps.OverlayView()) children used to respond to mouse events. I noticed they stopped doing so.

Here is an example ("overlay, click me" div should change its text to "worked for overlay" when clicked, but never does so):

http://savedbythegoog.appspot.com/?id=3fe560b541afaf7994e73a328d110f19e3864a06

Here is the code (cut/paste to https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/ for debugging), overlay child click listener is attached in USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd()

```
div.addEventListener("click", function(){ this.innerHTML="worked for overlay";});
```

// overlay-problem.js

```
var overlay;
USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

// Initialize the map and the custom overlay.

function initialize() {

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
  div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.className="findme";
  div.style.width="150px";
  div.style.height="150px";
  div.style.backgroundColor="red";
  div.innerHTML="NOT overlay, click me";

  div.addEventListener("click", function(){this.innerHTML="Thanks, it worked for a regular div";});
  document.body.appendChild(div);

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(62.323907, -150.109291),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var swBound = new google.maps.LatLng(62.281819, -150.287132);
  var neBound = new google.maps.LatLng(62.400471, -150.005608);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound, neBound);

  overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, map);
}

/** @constructor */
function USGSOverlay(bounds, map) {

  // Initialize all properties.
  this.bounds_ = bounds;
  this.map_ = map;
  this.div_ = null;

  // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay.
  this.setMap(map);
}

/**
 * onAdd is called when the map's panes are ready and the overlay has been
 * added to the map.
 */
USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {


  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
  div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.className="findme";
  div.style.width="150px";
  div.style.height="50px";
  div.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
  div.innerHTML="overlay, click me";
  div.addEventListener("click", function(){ this.innerHTML="worked for overlay";});
  this.div_ = div;

  // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
};

USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

  // We use the south-west and north-east
  // coordinates of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
  // To do this, we need to retrieve the projection from the overlay.
  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

  // Retrieve the south-west and north-east coordinates of this overlay
  // in LatLngs and convert them to pixel coordinates.
  // We'll use these coordinates to resize the div.
  var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
  var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

  var div = this.div_;
  div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
  div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
  div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
  div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
};

// The onRemove() method will be called automatically from the API if
// we ever set the overlay's map property to 'null'.
USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
  this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
  this.div_ = null;
};​
```

Comment: What [version of the API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning) are you using? The [issues list is reflecting a lot of issues similar to this in the experimental version.](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=&sort=-modified)

Comment: @geocodezip I was on v3.16. Question is answered (see below), still a mystery to me, though, how it was working till recently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should work if you change your overlay from:

```
panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
```

to:

```
panes.overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(div);
```

[From the docs:](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays#initialize)

> **overlayMouseTarget** contains elements that receive DOM mouse events,
>   such as the transparent targets for markers. It is above the
>   floatShadow, so that markers in the shadow of the info window can be
>   clickable.

---

**[Working js fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ByZNT/2/)** (Updated to contain styles of your overlay).

---

Cheers.

Comment: the only required change is to use the overlayMouseTarget-pane